# Prove that function $f$ is identical equal to $0$

Tags: analysis

Function $f$ is continuos on interval $[0, 1]$ and derivative on interval $(0, 1)$. Also apply $f(0) = 0$ and 
$|f'(x)|\le |f(x)|$ for every $x\in (0,1)$.
Prove that $f$ identical equal to $0$.

Any help for this exercise, I do not know how to prove it.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Let $x_0$ be such that $|f(x)|$ is maximized at $x = x_0$ and use the mean value theorem on $[0,x_0]$.